# How to send HTTPS response from a wordpress website to another

Tags: php, wordpress, https, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I know it's a little bit complicated but there's a lot of benefits for me using this scenario,

I'm working on a WordPress project and need to verify the user's license so I made an AJAX form has the required fields from user, Unfortunately the verification API needs a Secret Key (Belongs to me and cannot include in the client's project) so I made an external WordPress website (Subfolder on my website) and develop two small [Plugin & Theme].

**- In the client side**

I prepare the user sensitive data to send to my website using WordPress function (wp_safe_remote_get) like this...

```
$request_url = 'HTTPS://MY_WEBSITE/verify?api=XXX&some=XXX&some=XXX';

$response = wp_safe_remote_get( 

    $request_url, 

    array(
        'timeout' => 300
    )
);
```

**- On my Website**

1. The theme has an [3 files: style.css, functions.php and verify.php] and the verify.php has this line [ **do_action( 'xxx' )** ].
2. The plugin has [ add_action( 'xxx' ) ] in the constructor to do the verification process and of course I included the My SECRET KEY here ..
3. Collect $_GET params and verify then return an array with the result using [print_r] so the final result **exactly** like this from browser Inspect Element

   body_tag>

   Array (
             [API_RESULT] => Array ( 'verified' => true ); 
     )

   /body>

**The Issue**

In the client side I received the previous array BUT besides a lot of included scripts and css paths belongs to my WordPress website, So...

1. I need to receive only the response body without the other included files.
2. Is that secure enough?
3. Is there a solution for this scenario something like create a PHP file rather than a WordPress site but will be more secure??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I read this part: `Unfortunately the verification API needs a Secret Key(Belongs to me and cannot include in the project) `. So.. have you ever used public/private keys?

Comment: I'm including this Secret Key in my website's plugin of course to do the verification processes, Cannot include in the client's project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Server Side**

If you need to send an array to the client side, Do your processes you need then print serialized array.

**index.php**

```
do_action( 'YOUR_ACTION_NAME', 'VAR_1', 'VAR_2' );
```

**class_processes.php**

```
function __construct() {

    add_action( 'YOUR_ACTION_NAME', array( &$this, '__Trigger_User_Action' ), 10, 2 );

}

public function __Trigger_User_Action( $seller_name = '', $token_type ) {

    $user_final_data = array();

    // Do Some

    die( serialize( $user_final_data ) );

}
```

**2. Client Side**

```
$request_url = 'https://DOMAIN.XXX/user_processes?user_name=XXX&code=XXX';

$response = wp_safe_remote_get( 

     $request_url, 
         array(
            'timeout' => 300
         )
     );

     if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {

         $body_data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

         if( ! is_wp_error( $body_data ) ) {

             $user_server_data = @unserialize( $body_data );

         }

     }
```

Now **$user_server_data** contains the the array you passed in [print] function through your server.